# Only the topmost code in $(window).scroll is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've got some code in `$(window).scroll` that checks if an element is visible, then triggers another function.

However, only the first section of code is firing. Both bits of code work in and of themselves - if I swap their order, whichever is on top fires correctly.

My code is as follows:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function() {
 "use strict";
 var win = $(window), viewport = {
  top: win.scrollTop(),
  left: win.scrollLeft()
 }, bounds = this.offset();
 viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
 viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
 bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
 bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
 return !(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom);
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
 "use strict";

 var load_more_results = $("#ajax-load_more_results").isOnScreen();
 if (load_more_results === true) {LoadMoreResults();}

 var load_more_staff = $("#ajax-load_more_staff").isOnScreen();
 if (load_more_staff === true) {LoadMoreStaff();}
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you only fire one event from `$(window).scroll`? I assume not.

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console?  I'm pretty sure the error is within `LoadMoreResults` and `LoadMoreStaff` function.

Comment: The scroll event fires more than once per user scroll (actually a lot depending on the browser). There isn't anything I see that is obviously wrong. Can you provide a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: jsfiddle would be great to look in to the issue

Comment: @t.niese - It's definitively not the function, as I get the same problem if I just use alert("Hello") instead of calling the function.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin I don't see any problem when I run this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82yrsfgs/1/) where `LoadMoreResults` and `LoadMoreStaff` are replaced with `console.log`.

Comment: @t.niese - Thanks for the jsfiddle - I see what I've done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it - the answer was stupidly simple. The JS code was in my central js file, which is triggered on every page. The DIVs with those IDs only appear on certain pages, and if the DIV didn't exist at all, the code failed.

I solved it by moving those events only to the pages that included those DIVs. Thanks to @t.niese for the JSFiddle that made me realise this.

Comment: But then you should have seen a error message like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`

Comment: I *might* have forgotten to check the error console.